# How to configure two domains to use the same SSL certificate?

Tags: networking, ssl-certificate, subdomain

Let's say I have a single SSL certificate and would like to configure both a domain (wxyz.com) and its subdomain (subdomain.wxyz.com) to use the same cert, what's the best way to go about doing that?
(Using Nginx server)

Answer (score 1):

You should create the certificate for the specific host name (*subject name*) `subdomain.wxyz.com` and add a *subject alternate name* (SAN) with the plain second-level domain `wxyz.com`.